# google sheet: set a column as function of another

Tags: google-sheets

I have 2 columns on my google spreatsheed: Progress and Percentage.

I want Progress to be a function that takes the Percentage value at its row.

In a nutshell, if I write `3` on Percentage, it should write `|||` at Progress:

```
Progress   | Percentage 
|||        | 3
|||||||||| | 10
|||||      | 5
```

I'm totally new to Google sheets, how can I get this result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with REPT or SPARKLINE

```
=REPT("|",B2)
```

Comment: where exactly do I place this?

Comment: I'm choosing a cell B1 and writing into its ƒx `= REPT("|",B2)` and it appears `#ERROR!`. It gives me error in the cell even when I try ƒx `=REPT("|",3)`.

Comment: How can I write a formula that works for any row instead of just the row 2?

Comment: Solved by using `=REPT("|",B:B)`